# How to disable element naming prefix in asp.net mvc2 template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How to disable element prefix in asp.net mvc2 template?
Should I use Partial Control Instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question, this line of code removes the hierarchical prefix from the element name..

```
<% ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = ""; %>
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description) %>
```

Comment: But won't that remove the prefix on everything? What if you only wanted to affect one field?